# How can I programmatically seamlessly share a clients google calendar with a service account as automatically as possible

Tags: node.js, flutter, google-calendar-api, service-accounts, programmatically-created

I am trying to share a service account with any user's calendar and would like to know if anyone knows how to do so on the backend which is node.js or the frontend which is flutter/dart so that the user has to do as little as possible to add the service account to their calendar.

When onboarding a user on the flutter/dart front end I would like to ask a user if a service account can be added to a calendar on their account so the system can handle certain scheduling tasks for the user.  I am assuming that the user is not technical.  Ideally, I would like to add a new calendar to the user's account and share the service account with that.

After onboarding I would like all actions which the system does with the users calendar to take place on a node.js server using the service account.

I would like the service account to be able to read events from the user's calendar, add events, and find times during which the user is not already booked.

I have searched the internet for many hours and there is very little information about how to do this.

Also, will using a service account to view and modify and find available times on a user's calendar only work with workplace calendars and not with free calendars?

Comment: I have looked into services that can do this such as Nylas so I know this is possible.  However, those services are way too out of this free app budget.

Comment: Any update on implementation? I'm on basically the same path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are services/methods available using Calendar API that can achieve the functionality you want, you may look into the following:

- [Method: users.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) - for listing the users within your organization (as reference calendarId for the other methods needed)
- [Calendars:insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/calendars/insert) - for creating a secondary calendar.
- [Acl: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/acl/update) - for setting Access Control List to the created secondary calendar.
- [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/list) & [Events: get](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/get) - for listing and getting the specified event needed for modification.

Now, for creating and authorizing the service account for this, you may check this reference link for [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/auth).

Bear in mind that read/write access to events/calendars requires the correct scope as define on the link above.

> Here's the OAuth 2.0 scope information for the Google Calendar API:
>
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar read/write
> access to Calendars
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly read-only access to
> Calendars https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events read/write
> access to Events
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly  read-only
> access to Events
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly    read-only
> access to Settings
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute   run as a
> Calendar add-on

And lastly, service accounts have no rights/authorization to access personal Gmail accounts, since the [Domain-wide delegation feature](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) only applies to user accounts within your organization.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  One question is it possible to use oauth2 to access the calendar of a user external to the user running the app?  In particular to run the free-busy API call to find out when the external user is available.